# varbinary(max) datatype invalid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
CREATE TABLE Uploads
(
    id          uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DI_Id       INT              NOT NULL,
    FileData    VARBINARY(Max)   NULL,
    sFileName   nvarchar(50)     NOT NULL,
    ContentType nvarchar(50)     NOT NULL
)
```

I tried to create a table as above.

It produces an error incorrect near `varbinary(max)`.

If I give fixed column size like `varbinary(100)`, then no error occurs.

How can I declare `varbinary(max)` in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 should support this - are you sure you're not doing this on a SQL Server **2000** ?? Or is the compatibility level of your database set to 80 (= SQL Server 2000) ??

Comment: Incorrect syntax near varbinary.

Comment: Is there any substitute for varbinary(max) in sql 2000?

Comment: @user993935 - The `image` datatype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 **does** support `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

Either you're executing this CREATE TABLE statement against a SQL Server 2000 machine, or your database is still in the compatibility level= 80 (SQL Server 2000).

Check your compatibility level with this query:

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE name = 'yourdatabase'
```

If you get an error running this query - you're running against SQL Server 2000 :-)

If your database is level 80, you need to upgrade it to at least level 90 (SQL Server 2005):

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
```

Comment: Hi @marc_s thanks for your answer. The compatibility level of my DB is 120 but still having the same issue. First I have use the data type image. But changing that to varbinary(max) after reading about it's deprecation.